# Do I need to create jpa repository interface for each table in my single database. For doing CRUD operations on each table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

1. Do I need to create interface for each table in a Single Database.
2. Few tables are not mapped with each other.
3. How do I solve this issue. I have more than 40 tables in a single database.

   public interface RegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository {}

   public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository {}

Comment: Yes . Use JBOSS plugin for easiness.

Comment: can you please explain this little bit more. If possible any example

Comment: Are you looking for reverse engineering right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for reverse enginnering

install jboss hibernate tools plugin in your eclipse.

and follow the instructions given in the documentation

https://tools.jboss.org/features/hibernate.html

This tool that can generate model classes and mapping files from database.

Comment: No, I just want to know, is this possible to make CRUD operations with each tables in single database without creating jpa repository interface for each of the table. As there are more than 40 tables in my single database and few of them are not mapped with each other.